# How to store tax (VAT) value in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Could someone tell me how to store a VAT value in SQL and during the calculation? For now I am storing into SQL like `decimal(4, 2)`. Everything is OK during the call up process. I retrieve data from SQL into a datagridview and there data is displayed like I stored it into the database.

But the VAT value is stored in this format `1.18` for `18.00%` for calculation purpose. But I want into the VAT column into the datagridview to be a kind of a mask for VAT filed (data to be displayed `18.00` not `1.18`)

Here is the declared data columns

```
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "Barcode";
    dc.ReadOnly = true;
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn();
    dc2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc2.ColumnName = "NAME";
    dc2.ReadOnly = true;

    DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn();
    dc4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc4.ColumnName = "PRICE";
    dc4.ReadOnly = false;

    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn();
    dc3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc3.ColumnName = "QTY";
    DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn();
    dc5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc5.ColumnName = "TVSH";
    dc5.ReadOnly = false;

    DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn();
    dc6.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc6.ColumnName = "Total";
    dc6.Expression = "Price* QTY";//Multiplying the Price and Quantity DataColumns
    dc6.ReadOnly = true;

    DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn();
    dc7.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc7.ColumnName = "WithoutVAT";
    dc7.Expression = "Total/ VAT";//Multiplying the Price and Quantity DataColumns
    dc7.ReadOnly = true ;

    DataColumn dc9 = new DataColumn();
    dc9.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
    dc9.ColumnName = "VATvalue";
    dc9.Expression = "Total- WithoutVAT";//Multiplying the Price and Quantity DataColumns
    dc9.ReadOnly = true ;
```

What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should  better to store the values as they conceptually are. I would suggest to store the vat as 0.18 in the database as decimal and change  the calculation logic:

```
value = x * (1+ vat)
```

Then you can show the vat nicely in the presentation using percentage formater:

```
vat.ToString("P")
```

You may also add a constraint for the vat field in the database to make sure it never exceeds 1.00